# Date Time math (A little Detail Missing)

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

Ok, so I have this method, where I'm trying to subtract one date from the other, and then divide it by an integer number:

```
public void BonoDatos () {

    //public InputField StartTimeBono;
    //public InputField FinishBono;
    //DateTime BonoStart Datetime BonoFinish
    //public InputField NumeroDeBonos;
    //int NumDeBonos;

    NumDeBonos = int.Parse (NumeroDeBonos.text);
    BonoStart = DateTime.ParseExact (StartTimeBono.text, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
    BonoFinish = DateTime.ParseExact (FinishBono.text, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);

    Start2 = DateTime.Now;

    BonoPeriodo = (int)((BonoFinish.Subtract(BonoStart).TotalSeconds) / NumDeBonos);

    print (BonoPeriodo);
    print ("funciona");

    if (MaquinasGanadoras.text.Length > 0) {

        NumGanador.text = Maquina.text;
        CancelInvoke ("NumerAzarBono");
        print (NumGanador.text);

    } else if (MaquinasGanadoras.text.Length == 0) {

        Invoke ("NumerAzarBono", 0.1f);
        print ("Numero al Azar");
    }
}
```

Now, this code is supposed to take the difference of time between the two dates, and then divide it by the integer, in this case "NumdeBonos" so that the code I have in the update repeats the amount of times I put NumDeBonos to be. For example if I divide the difference between 5, in that amount of time, I need my update to happen 5 times. Problem is, My update isn't working. This is the code:

```
    if(DateTime.Now.Equals(Start2.AddSeconds(BonoPeriodo))) {
    //if(DateTime.Now.Equals(DateTime.Now, Start2.AddSeconds(BonoPeriodo))) {

        print ("PERIOD FUNCIONA");

        PagPrincipal.SetActive(false);

        Bonos.SetActive(true);

        Invoke ("apagaBonos",5f);

        Start2 = DateTime.Now;


    }
```

Now, it doesn't show any mistakes, it just doesn't do anything. What little detail am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` has a millisecond resolution, and when you use `DateTime.Now` you'll be getting the timestamp for "now" to the full resolution of the type. You're comparing to a pre-recorded `DateTime`, adjusted by two whole seconds, but unless that exact line of code happens to run with in the exact millisecond that "now" is *exactly two seconds* ahead of what `Start2` holds, it will never execute.

If you only care about seconds-resolution, use the properties of `DateTime` to compare their year/month/day/hour/minute/second directly or create new `DateTime`s manually, stripping them down to seconds-level resolution:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var target = Start2.AddSeconds(BonoPeriodo);
if (now.Minutes == target.Minutes && now.Seconds == target.Seconds...)
```

Or use greater-than checks:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var target = Start2.AddSeconds(BonoPeriodo);
if (now > target)...
```

The default equality check for `DateTime` will compare to the full resolution of the type.

Comment: Come Again? I deleted Now from the update and it only marked it as an error

Comment: I didn't mean to remove the use of Now; see my edit.

Comment: Ok, so I add both of those vars and change the if and it should work?

Comment: Cool, now it activates the screen, but it's not letting me input the date first.

Comment: I'm gonna try to put that update part to the void, see how that works out